# How to use DisplayForModel() to show a list of Customers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Normally we use `DisplayForModel` or `EditorForModel` to display and edit a single Customer object, respectively.

How to display a list of Customers using these templating scheme?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming you have a collection of customers in your view model

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

you could use the following in your view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Customers)
```

and then in the editor/display template (`~/Views/Home/DisplayTemplates/Customer.cshtml` or `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Customer.cshtml`):

```html
@model AppName.Model.Customer
<div>@Model.Name</div>
```

The Customer partial will be then rendered for each element of the customers collection of your main model. The important thing is the naming convention: the partial should be situated in a DisplayTemplates subfolder and called the same as the collection type (`Customer`).

Comment: Is there a way to specify a template name to something else? Customer Model is the same but if you would like to show it in different template? this doesnt work like DisplayFor(x=>x.Customers,"CustomerGridView") ?

Answer (score 2):

How about following Haack's [tutorial](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-tabular-display-template.aspx) ?

> As great as this feature is, there is
>   one template that’s conspicuously
>   missing. ASP.NET MVC does not include
>   a template for displaying a list of
>   objects in a tabular format.
>
> Earlier
>   today, ScottGu forwarded an email from
>   Daniel Manes (what?! no blog! ;) with
>   a question on how to accomplish this.
>   Daniel had much of it implemented, but
>   was trying to get over the last
>   hurdle. With Brad’s help, I was able
>   to give him a boost over that hurdle.
>   Let’s walk through the scenario.