# DisplayFor() compilation error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, .net-4.5

I am trying to render my views using DisplayForModel and EditorForModel helper function.
As the first step, I have the list controller that writtens Ienumarable list of organizations.

I have followed the answers of Darian from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825620/how-to-use-displayformodel-to-show-a-list-of-customers), and did as below.

In - list.cshtml

```
@using PartyBiz.Models.Objects
@model IEnumerable<Organization>

@Html.DisplayFor( model => model.Organizations )
```

In - Organization.cshtml

```
@model PartyBiz.Models.Objects.Organization

<div>@Model.Caption </div>

<div>@Model.Description  </div>

<div>@Model.NameInUse  </div>
```

My model has the below property

```
public IEnumerable<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }
```

Controller list action

```
public ViewResult List(OrganizationQuery qry = null)
{
    return View(OrganizationRepo.All() as IEnumerable<Organization>);
}
```

However I am getting the compile error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061:
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   does not contain a definition for 'Organizations' and no extension
>   method 'Organizations' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

please advise what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: @using PartyBiz.Models.Objects gives me the hint of using to import related model...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `List.cshtml`. You need to change it to soemthing like bellow:

@using PartyBiz.Models.Objects
@model IEnumerable

```
@foreach(var m in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor( m => m.Organizations )
}
```

Comment: thanku for the comment. I am looking for something without foreach, may I have not clearly mentioned that..

Comment: @mmssddff how you would like to show every element without foreach? it is impossible

Answer (score 0):

Since your model is already an IEnumerable, what you really need is

```
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

or

```
@Html.DisplayForModel("Organization") //explicitly provide template name
```

The question you have referenced assumed that there was another model class with property `Customers` that could be enumerated. Your situation is a bit different.

Comment: this will display proxy entities as below:System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Party_A9AAEA1B13CDAAAE6 - there is some long text ofcourse

Comment: @mmssddff, then you can try `DispalyForModel` - please see the update.

Comment: DisplayForModel will work only for single organization, I am not able to show list of organizations using DisplayForModel...

Comment: @mmssddff, have you tried it? For all I know it should work provided your model is `IEnumerable<Organization>` and you have a template defined for single `Organization`.